# Why is my form being processed as an HTML request instead of JS?

Tags: jquery, ruby-on-rails

I am developing on Rails 3.0.3 and using jQuery. Here is my javascipt include tag:

```
<%= javascript_include_tag "http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.6.1/jquery.min.js", "rails.js" %>
```

I want to send a JS request on change of a dropdown and wrote the following code to do so. This form does not get processed as JS, but is getting processed as an HTML request instead:

```
<% form_tag(aggregatedata_path, :method=>'post', :id => "dd-container", :remote => true ) do %>
    <%= select_tag( 
        :group, 
        options_for_select(groups_list, @group), 
        {
            :id => "dd", 
            :onchange => "this.form.submit();"
        } ) %>
<% end %>
```

I read a similar post on SO that suggested the problem was the js library, but unless there's no other way, I'd rather avoid changing that at this point lest a million other things break. I have another form that gets processed as a JS request just fine. Here it is:

```
<% form_tag(poweroutput_path, :method=>'post', :id => "date-form", :remote => true ) do %>
    <%= text_field_tag(
        'dt', nil,
        {  
            :id => 'date-field',
            :class => 'dateformat-d-dt-m-dt-Y',
            :value => Time.now.getlocal.strftime("%d.%m.%Y")             
        }) %>
    <%= submit_tag " ", :id => "go-button" %>
<% end %>
```

The only obvious difference I see is that the first one uses `:onchange => "this.form.submit();"` while the second does not. Is there something in that function that overrides my earlier `:remote => true`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I agree with Dave. Since you are already using jQuery, I'd go with something like this:

```
$('#dd-container').change(function(){
  $.ajax({
    type: "POST",
    url: your_path,
    data: $(this).find('option:selected').attr('value'),
    success: function( response ) {
      console.log( response );
    }
  });
});
```

Oh, and don't forget to remove the `:onchange => "this.form.submit();"` and `, :remote => true` from your form.

Comment: Thanks so much! I'm very new to all of this and have mostly been using rails helpers that do all the work for me, but leave me wondering what's going on. Examples like this are really helpful!

Answer (score 1):

The first hit I get when I search for "Rails 3 remote form" pulls up this link:

http://www.alfajango.com/blog/rails-3-remote-links-and-forms/

It explains it in the first set of bullet points discussing what `:remote => true` does:

> 1. It finds remote links, forms, and inputs, and overrides their click events to submit to the server via AJAX.

Since you're submitting the form manually, I'd think any click handlers are being bypassed.

Comment: Thanks so much for taking the time to respond! Now understand why that wasn't working!